# Appending to nested list in python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a dictionary with a nested list as values (actually thousands of entries, here just a simplification).

```
my_dict = {'topic a': [['CategoryA', 230], ['CategoryB', 270]], 'topic b': [['CategoryA', 198], ['CategoryB', 188]]}
```

I further have two lists with float values (ordered and same amount as list values): `list_A: [0.1, 0.1], list_B: [0.2, 0.2]`

I wish to iterate over the dictionary and lists and per iteration step append the float values of A to the first nested list of the dictionary's item and the float values of B to the second nested list of the dictionary's item. The order has to remain as it is.

My desired outcome is as follows:

```
{'topic a': [['CategoryA', 230, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 270, 0.2]], 'topic b': [['CategoryA', 198, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 188, 0.2]]}
```

I have tried so many things; the iteration just won't quite work. Please see the code of one of my attempts:

```
my_dict = {'topic a': [['CategoryA', 230], ['CategoryB', 270]], 'topic b': [['CategoryA', 198], ['CategoryB', 188]]}

list_A = [0.1, 0.1]
list_B = [0.2, 0.2]

for element in my_dict.values():
        for el in list_A:
            element[0].append(el) 
        for el_ in list_B:
            element[1].append(el_)
print(my_dict)
```

The undesired outcome is:

```
{'topic a': [['CategoryA', 230, 0.1, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 270, 0.2, 0.2]], 'topic b': [['CategoryA', 198, 0.1, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 188, 0.2, 0.2]]}
```

I also tried a workaround with zip, also no success it says 'TypeError: 'list' object is not callable' when trying to convert zip to list.

```
test = []
for element in my_dict.values():
    test = zip(element[0], list_A)
test = list(test)
print(test)
```

For my first example I actually understand why I get the undesired outcome but just can't get to the desired one; for the zip attempt I do not see the problem. Any (pythonic) ideas? - Very much appreciated!

**Update:**
Dictionary transformed to list, still not working; what am I missing?

```
my_list = []
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    temp = [key,value]
    my_list.append(temp)
print(my_list)  

# output: [['topic a', [['CategoryA', 230], ['CategoryB', 270]]], ['topic b', [['CategoryA', 198], ['CategoryB', 188]]]]


list_A = [0.1, 0.1]
list_B = [0.2, 0.2]


for element in my_list:
        for el in list_A:
            element[1][0].append(el) 
        for el_ in list_B:
            element[1][1].append(el_)
print(my_list)

# output: [['topic a', [['CategoryA', 230, 0.1, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 270, 0.2, 0.2]]], ['topic b', [['CategoryA', 198, 0.1, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 188, 0.2, 0.2]]]]


test = []
for element in my_list:
    test = zip(element[1][0], list_A)
test = list(test)
print(test)

# output: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: I have a question. There is an order in your list A and list B, but how do we determine in which order these floats are added to each element in an unordered dictionary, are we just relying on the iteration over the dict values for order?

Comment: We can help you with this, but to be honest this is the wrong data structure for what you want to do.

Comment: Hi Richard K Yu, thanks for responding. I thought the dictionary was ordered... maybe that is the root of all my problems. The order I aim at in the dictionary is to be as it is written down.

Comment: Thanks already; I suppose I need to convert the dictionary to a list and try again from there.

Comment: Ok, I transformed the dictionary to a list, unfortunately my problems remain the same. What am I missing? Especially regarding the for-loop I really don't know how to append single list elements instead of the whole list; probably really obvious but I'm stuck.. Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, since there are infinitely many interpretations of your request, I don't think this is actually what you want, but let's start from here:

```
my_dict = {'topic a': [['CategoryA', 230], ['CategoryB', 270]],
           'topic b': [['CategoryA', 198], ['CategoryB', 188]]}

list_A = [0.1, 0.1]
list_B = [0.2, 0.2]

desired = {'topic a': [['CategoryA', 230, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 270, 0.2]],
           'topic b': [['CategoryA', 198, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 188, 0.2]]}

for outerlist, column in zip(my_dict.values(), zip(list_A, list_B)):
    for nestedlist, floatvalue in zip(outerlist, column):
        nestedlist.append(floatvalue)

assert my_dict == desired
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Veky that is the answer - or better one of the probably infinite possible answers indeed - I was looking for; I just could not get my coding attempts to work.

Comment: So this code actually works on your "thousands of entries" and gives what you want? I'm honestly surprised. :-D

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
dict_keys = list(my_dict.keys())

for i in range(0, len(list_A)):
    val_A = list_A[i]
    val_B = list_B[i]

    my_dict[dict_keys[i]][0].append(val_A)
    my_dict[dict_keys[i]][1].append(val_B)

print(my_dict)
# {'topic a': [['CategoryA', 230, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 270, 0.2]], 'topic b': [['CategoryA', 198, 0.1], ['CategoryB', 188, 0.2]]}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaz Miller; this also works yes and helps me to understand where I was wrong!